# How do I make a command to reply to a certain user ID?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm setting up a whitelist and I want to use discord user IDs to use as a whitelist. I'm wondering if there is a way to make a command only work for certain user IDs?

I've tried many different methods from my own knowledge and other help forums with no luck.

```
const userId = message.guild.members.find(m => m.id === "212277222248022016");
if(!message.author === userId) {
    message.author.send("Whitelisted")
}else{
    message.author.send("Not whitelisted")
}
```

I wanted the user ID `212277222248022016` to get a dm saying "Whitelisted" but I always end up getting the dm "Not whitelisted".

---

I figured out the fix for this issue in case anyone comes across this thread and wants to know:

```
const userId = client.users.get("id here");
if (message.author === userId) {
    message.author.send("Whitelisted")
} else {
    message.author.send("Not whitelisted")
}
```

Comment: Try removing the "!"

Comment: Get rid of the ! in the if statement

Comment: Removing the ! didn't fix it.

Comment: Instead of editing the question to include the solution, post an answer (which is perfectly okay). You'll be able to accept it in two days, but won't get reputation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!`

```
const userId = message.guild.members.find(m => m.id === "212277222248022016");
if (message.author === userId) {
message.author.send("Whitelisted")
} else {
message.author.send("Not whitelisted")
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix it - I'm still getting the "Not whitelisted" DM.

Comment: console.log(message.author) and console.log(userId); what do you see?

Comment: They both show information about my profile - even the console.log(userId)

Comment: `userID` is a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). `message.author` is a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). The two objects are therefore *not* equal.